# lifo queues as optics

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens, lenses

Consider a list of items `[a]` and a pair of functions

```
pop :: [a] -> (Maybe a, [a])
pop = headMay &&& tailSafe

push :: a -> [a] -> [a]
push = (:)
```

which just provide the list with a last in-first out queue structure.

I might be wrong, but the API of this feels very `lens`y, providing a way to accessing the first element of the list. Still it is neither a `Lens` nor a `Prism`.

I was wondering it this could be implemented as a `Traversal` or some other optics structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pushing and popping at the list head can be expressed as a prism -- from an `[a]` to maybe an `(a, [a])`, and from an `(a, [a])` back to an `[a]`. That exists in *lens* as [`_Cons`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.18.1/docs/Control-Lens-Cons.html#v:Cons):

```
_Cons @[a] @[b] :: Prism [a] [b] (a, [a]) (b, [b])
```

(This only diverges from your API by expressly ruling out getting a non-empty list but not an element from `pop`, as a `(Maybe a, [a])` result type would, in principle, allow.)

Comment: thanks. As far as I understand, `_Cons` just allows to treat a list as a pair of head and tail. It does not allow to push an element in the front on the list. If I'm wrong, please correct me showing how to implement `pop` and `push` using `_Cons`

Comment: @marcosh Prisms can be inverted using [`review`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.18.1/docs/Control-Lens-Review.html#v:review) (or its operator spelling, `(#)`).